# How to use animatedPosition prop in react-native-bottom-sheet

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I would like to be able to track my BottomSheet, grabbing the values with each pixel it moves along the y-axis if possible. I am using [this library](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props#animatedposition), I thought using the prop animatedPosition could help but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I have a [snack example here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/bottom-sheet-y-value) that reproduces my issue exactly as well as the code below.

EDIT: I also noticed there is an onChange prop, maybe I can use this in combination with animatedProp to achieve what I need?

UPDATED code

```
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {useSharedValue, useDerivedValue} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import MapView  from 'react-native-maps';
export default function App(){
  const animatedPosition = useSharedValue(0);
  const snapPoints = [100, 200, 500];
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(0);

  useDerivedValue(() => {
    console.log(animatedPosition.value, 'here you will get value of every position');
  }, [animatedPosition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentPosition);
  }, [currentPosition]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      >

     
      <BottomSheet
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        animatedPosition={animatedPosition}
        onChange={index => setCurrentPosition(index)}
        index={0}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          }}
        />
      </BottomSheet> 
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[animatedPosition](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#animatedposition) return [shared-values](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/shared-values/) of [Reanimated](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated) which can be used to animate/interpolate other views in the screen

[onchange](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#onchange) callback will give you current snap position like 1,2,3

[animatedPosition](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props/#animatedposition) will give you the value of every pixel

## Example

```
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet/src';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {useSharedValue, useDerivedValue} from 'react-native-reanimated';
const App = () => {
  const animatedPosition = useSharedValue(0);
  const snapPoints = [100, 200, 500];
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = React.useState(0);

  useDerivedValue(() => {
    console.log(animatedPosition.value, 'here you will get value of every position');
  }, [animatedPosition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentPosition);
  }, [currentPosition]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        animatedPosition={animatedPosition}
        onChange={index => setCurrentPosition(index)}
        index={0}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
          }}
        />
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: I tried to get your example to work but it gives me an error. Did you test this? I have your example posted here https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/talking-truffle

Comment: Please check that and let me know what you think, I originally thought it might be because your BottomSheet import has /src at the end which I do not think is needed but it made no difference.

Comment: @guts716 I tested it on a real project it was working. Gorham's bottom sheet doesn't work on the snack. can you test this code on real project

Comment: Yes, it will have to wait a bit before I can test though. I will upvote and award answer now and bounty once I test. I wont forget about it. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Also, are you sure it does not work in snack? If you look at the snack example I included in my original post, the bottom sheet works in that snack?

Comment: @guts716 the snack you attached is also not working. i am sure it is not working on snack

Comment: weird, I am able to get it working for me. Who knows.

Comment: I have noticed you are using a different library than me. Can you confirm you are able to use this code using the library I included in my original post?

Comment: @guts716 we are using same library

Comment: If we are using the same library, why does the updated code in my post not work? The only difference is I use the import I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: @guts716 you are using now `reanimated-bottom-sheet` and i am using `@gorhom/bottom-sheet`. i think, you have changed library

Comment: @guts716 you should use `@gorhom/bottom-sheet`

Comment: When I switch over to that import, I cannot get the bottom sheet to work. I am rendering my BottomSheet in a MapView and that does not work using your import. Can you try to get it working with the import I provided since thats the library I am using? They seem to be different libraries. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gorhom/bottom-sheet
https://www.npmjs.com/package/reanimated-bottom-sheet

Comment: if you add this `@gorhom/bottom-sheet` what type of error do you get. i can help you to run this library because the one which you are using, is using older approch

Comment: I just updated the code in my post to what I have. When rendering the bottomSheet using the @gorhom import, the screen just becomes completely white and non interactive. Thank you for the continued help, I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ive tried to find some solutions for my issue but no luck